# Search and create new List<>

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

i have function which return list as given below.

```
 List<User> lstUsers = SearchUsers(searchText);
```

which gives a result like below

```
Username    AddedDate

--------    ---------
sa          02/02/2010
ba          02/02/2011
ta          02/02/2009
```

Its gives a reult that is not a problem.I want to create new list filter by date. For example just want a result between  the date  `01/01/2009` and `02/02/2010`.Is there any method in asp to filter a list.
 `List<User> lstFilterUsers =  \\Want Help Here(Filterd new List);`
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQ is great for this:

```
List<User> filteredUsers = lstUsers.Where(u => u.AddedDate >= dateFrom && u.AddedDate <= dateTo).ToList();
```

If you can't use LINQ, use a delegate instead:

```
List<User> filteredUsers = lstUsers.FindAll(delegate(User u) 
{
    return u.AddedDate >= dateFrom && u.AddedDate <= dateTo;
});
```

**EDIT:** If you're dealing with search strings, and your `AddedDate` property is of type `DateTime` you will have to do some string parsing first, e.g.:

```
private List<User> SearchUsers(string dateFrom, string dateTo)
{
    List<User> filteredUsers = lstUsers.FindAll(delegate(User u) 
    {
        return u.AddedDate >= DateTime.Parse(dateFrom) && u.AddedDate <= DateTime.Parse(dateTo);
    });
}
```

Then bind the list to your grid:

```
gdvUsers.DataSource = SearchUsers(dateFrom, dateTo);
gdvUsers.DataBind();
```

Comment: any idea about using above `delegate` to `DataSource` for grid.I use  `gdvUser.DataSource = (filteredUsers);` but it gives null.Thanks.

Comment: You might have to call DataBind on your grid after setting the datasource, e.g. `gdvUser.DataSource = filteredUsers; gdvUser.DataBind();` If the result is still blank, make sure that your filter is not possibly too narrow.

Comment: in database date is in the format`2011-12-30 17:40:42.727` and when we search given date have only `mm/yy/dd`.There is not any time.I think this is a problem?Any idea to solve the problem thanks.

Comment: What datatype is `User.AddedDate`? If it's a `DateTime` then you might have to cast your search string into a DateTime object when you filter. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use LINQ extension methods:

```
var dateFrom = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2009");
var dateTo = DateTime.Parse("02/02/2010");
lstUsers.Where(u=> u.AddedDate >= dateFrom && u.AddedDate <= dateTo).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lstUsers = (from user in lstUSers where user.AddedDate > dateTime1 && user.AddedDate < dateTime2 select user).ToList();
```

here dateTime1  = 01/01/2009 and dateTime2 = 02/02/2010

Answer (score 0):

As others have said Linq is the way to go to solve this problem.  The one thing you should keep in mind is where does the filtering occur.  When you use a Where clause on a list, the entire contents of the list get loaded into memory and the filter is applied.  If you execute the Where clause on a type that implements IQueryable, the datasource is responsible for filtering the data.  This has huge implications if you are searching in a database or ODATA source.